# Displaying iPhone's battery on an Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I am trying to display the iPhone's remaining battery level on a label in my apple watch app. I've tried using WatchConnectivity and sending messages between iphone and Apple Watch, but didn't work. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what errors you encountered. You should indeed use `WatchConnectivity` framework to communicate with the iPhone from the Watch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First just enable battery monitoring:

```
UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
```

Then you can create a computed property to return the battery level:

```
var batteryLevel: Float {
    return UIDevice.current.batteryLevel
}
```

To monitor your device battery level you can add an observer for the  `UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange` notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryLevelDidChange), name: .UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange, object: nil)
func batteryLevelDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    print(batteryLevel)
}
```

You can also verify the battery state:

```
var batteryState: UIDeviceBatteryState {
    return UIDevice.current.batteryState
}
case .unknown   //  "The battery state for the device cannot be determined."
case .unplugged //  "The device is not plugged into power; the battery is discharging"
case .charging  //  "The device is plugged into power and the battery is less than 100% charged."
case .full      //   "The device is plugged into power and the battery is 100% charged."
```

and add an observer for `UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange` notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryStateDidChange), name: .UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChange, object: nil)
func batteryStateDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    switch batteryState {
    case .unplugged, .unknown:
        print("not charging")
    case .charging, .full:
        print("charging or full")
    }
}
```

Now you have all the properties you need regarding your battery. Just pass them to the watch!

Hope this helps.